# How to override and add visualforce page to the button

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, button-overrides

I already have in my Visualforce page the following:

`<apex:page Controller="CandidateController" >`

if I add to this:
  `<apex:page standardController="Candidate__c" Controller="CandidateController"`
getting this error:

> Error Error: A custom and standard controller cannot be referenced in
>   the same page.

How do you wire-up the custom Visualforce page to a default button? what I meant is that if you click on the `New` or `New Candidate` as shown in the below screen shots it gives me the standard page layout but instead I want to override to the Visualforce page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps to override standard action with custom visualforce page.

1. Create a new visualforce page by defining that object as standard controller as shown below

   `<apex:page standardcontroller="Candidate__c"></apex:page>`
2. Override the standard new action of that object.

Go to detail page of your object and look for button related list as shown below

[image]

click on edit against New Label and on the next screen visualforce which you have created in step 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, please see my updated question getting error

Comment: that is correct you can't use both at the same time. Make it as follows :<apex:page standardController="Candidate__c" extensions="CandidateController"

Comment: now getting this error `Error: Unsupported attribute extension in <apex:page> in Candidate at line 1 column 79 
`

Comment: it is extensions not extension :)